# Generate array of random number without duplicates

Tags: c#, arrays, random, arraylist

I want to make an array of random numbers without any duplicate.

```
private void SetRandomQuestions()
{
    var idS = from t in _db.QuestionsTables
              where t.Cat_Id == _catId
              select new
                     { t.Question_Id };

    // to get the questions Id from database table
    foreach (var variable in idS)
    {
        array.Add(variable.Question_Id);
    }

    // generate a random numbers depends on the array list values
    var random = new Random();

    for (var i = 0; i < _randomQuestionId.Length; i++)
    {
        _randomNumber = random.Next(array.Count);

        for (var j = 0; j < _randomQuestionId.Length; j++)
        {
            if (_randomQuestionId[j] != array[int.Parse(_randomNumber.ToString())])
            {
                _randomQuestionId[i] = array[int.Parse(_randomNumber.ToString())];
                j = 5;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see here I have list array has values of questions id and further I have created another array to get 4 elements randomly from that array.
However, my question is how I can get the elements without any duplicate Ids I have tried many times but unfortunately I didn't success with that.

Comment: Look into array shuffling.

Comment: Can't flag for more duplicates. But there's a dupe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195738/avoiding-random-duplicates) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473321/generating-random-unique-values-c-sharp) also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561742/generate-distinct-random-numbers-in-c-sharp) then [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299138/generate-n-random-and-unique-numbers-within-a-range) and probably an other dozen.

Comment: And why the heck are converting the numer to string and back? (`int.Parse(_randomNumber.ToString())])`)

Comment: Olivier, It was suppose to add values of an array list randomly in array of integers.
but I used array shuffling instead of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing would be *shuffling* your question ids and then taking the first four.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
randomQuestionId = idS.OrderBy(_ => rnd.Next()).Take(4).ToArray();
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567/is-using-random-and-orderby-a-good-shuffle-algorithm) for a more efficient way to shuffle an array (using the [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)).

Comment: I guess yes, it is the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this code will generate unique random numbers

```
int smallestNumber = 1;
int biggestNumber = 50;

//Determine the amount of random numbers
int amountOfRandomNumbers = 10;

//Create a list of numbers from which the routine
//shall choose the result numbers
var possibleNumbers = new List<int>();
for (int i = smallestNumber; i <= biggestNumber; i++)
    possibleNumbers.Add(i);

var result = new List<int>();

//Initialize a random number generator
Random rand = new Random();

//For-loop which picks each round a unique random number
for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRandomNumbers; i++)
{
     //Generate random number
     int randomNumber = rand.Next(1, possibleNumbers.Count) - 1;  
     result.Add(possibleNumbers[randomNumber]);       
     //Remove the chosen result number from possible numbers list
     possibleNumbers.RemoveAt(randomNumber);
}
```

//Now loop on `result` and print the output

Answer (score 0):

```
var pickFour = array
    .OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())
    .Take(4);
```

Comment: Numeric operations are not needed here, the GUID is only used to randomize the list and are not selected.